# Sql function or bash script to get the memory usage of each query in postgres

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, postgresql-9.4

How to get memory usage and cpu utilization of of each query in postgres, I'm wondering if there is any sql function or script for the same

Answer (score -1):

Use `@` table concept and insert data, use that table data where you want but with same stored procedure